# Dynamically expanding CollectionView : Height of the CollectionView itself (not the items) changing when adding new items

Tags: height, collectionview

I'm trying to build a calendar in which I need to insert different lists for each day. I figured the collection view under each label of a number in the month would be the best and it works so far. I only have a problem with adding new items to the collection view. It's not growing, I have to scroll down.

I'm looking for a solution that could give the possibility to dynamically extend the height of the collection view without touching the height of the items. As there are 40 "mini" collection views on the page, I need to be able to grow the height of all the collection views at once, without having each one of them growing above the text beneath.

Here's my code for the viewDidLoad:

```
houseNameLabelList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"House 1", @"House 2", @"House 3", @"House 4", @"House 5", nil];   // The array of the titles I want to display
NSInteger rowCount = [houseNameLabelList count];
CGFloat height = rowCount * 17;   // 17 is the height of each item in the collection view
self.myCollectionView.frame = CGRectMake(self.myCollectionView.frame.origin.x, self.myCollectionView.frame.origin.y, 45, height);  // 45 is the width of my collection view
```

Of course I have delegate and datasource set as "self".

The initial height of the collection view is 51 (3*17 which means 3 items), and I want it to grow to 85 (5 * 17 for the 5 items in my array).

How can I do that ?
Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

When adding a new item, the `collectionView.contentView.bounds` is changed.

I think you can expand the collectionView through call `collectionView.bounds = collectionView.contentView.bounds`